# how to get session id on client side in apache httpclient

Tags: java, web-services, httpclient, session-variables, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am authenticating trying to login to a webservice with username and pwd.
Then I have to use sessionid in subsequent we calls . I am using apache HttpClient (legacy version) 2.0.2 .

Below is my client side code to authenticate . My question is , how do I get session Id after I authenticate and How to use same session id in subsequent calls .

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
public class TestHttpClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            GetMethod get = new HttpGet("www.google.com");

            org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials upc =
                    new org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "pwd");

            client.getState().setCredentials(null, null, upc);

            get.setDoAuthentication(true);

            client.setConnectionTimeout(60000);

            client.executeMethod(get);

            System.out.println(get.getResponseBodyAsString());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for helping newbie in web development.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get the Session id:

```
.......

client.executeMethod(get); 

Header[] headers=get.getResponseHeader("jsessionid");

if(headers!=null && headers.length>0){

 String sessionId=headers[0].getValue();

}
```

I am sure there would be better way to handle the authenticated session without you reading the session id reciprocating.